# Heroku web UI log viewer

Tags: heroku

I wonder if there is a more friendly way ( using some GUI) to view Heroku application's logs than through a console?

Answer (score 4):

I think papertrail (heroku addon) is the best option, it is similar to console logs, with search, and you can achive the logs daily to amazon S3.

Answer (score 2):

Not at the moment.

You can however use the logs drain add-on to pipe your applications to a running syslog on a separate server, like outlined in the [heroku docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#syslog_drains).

After that, you could use a tool like [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) to analyze your logs in a nice Web UI.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The [Loggly Heroku add-on](http://addons.heroku.com/loggly) might be a good option.